# If $a$ is an integer, prove that $\gcd(14a + 3, 21a + 4) = 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

If $a$ is an integer, prove that gcd$(14a+3,21a+4)=1$.

I want to know if my proof is correct or if I should start over because I did something wrong.

My proof is as followed:

Assume $a \in Z$.
Wts: gcd$(14a+3,21a+4)=1$.
By theorem we know that $(14a+3)x+y(21a+4)=1$. So, let $x=3$ and $y=-2$. Thus, $(14a+3)(3)+(-2)(21a+4)=1$. Hence, gcd$(14a+3,21a+4)=1$.

Comment: No, this is not correct. You are already assuming that the gcd is $1$ in saying "By theorem" (which one?). The last two sentences are all right. So you should improve the beginning.

Comment: Just change that sentence to: To show that $\text{gcd}(14a+3,21a+4)=1$, it will suffice to produce $x,y$ such that $(14a+3)x +(21a+4)y=1$.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks! http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your solution is correct. It follows from $$(14a+3)(3)+(-2)(21a+4)=1$$

There is no need for assumption of existence of $x$ and $y$. You showed that they exist, namely $x=3$ and $y=-2$.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the first sentence to prove the result. Start with " Let x=3 and y=-2...." and your proof will be good.

Comment: Okay I will take that out. Thank you!

Comment: So far, it is still in.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Idea:}$

$$(14a+3)(3)+(21a+4)(-2) = 1.$$

We know that $\gcd((14a + 3), (21a + 4)) = n \geq 1$, then $n|(14a+3)$ and $n|(21a+4)$. Therefore $n|1 \therefore n = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use that

$$\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,sa+tb)$$

then

$$\gcd(14a+3,21a+4)=\gcd(42a+9,42a+8)=\gcd(42a+9-42a-8,42a+8)=\\=\gcd(1,42a+8)=1$$